# Why can't I target an image in a table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, find, html-table

The idea is to show some extra content in TDs on hover, as well as increase the size of images in the rest of the row at the same time without breaking image proportions.

I'm using this JS:

```
$('tr.therow').hover(function() {
$(this).find('img.theimage').css("height", "100px");
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/J2YAj/

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do this with pure CSS and the `:hover` pseudo-selector I think if you wanted.

Comment: And jQuery isnt loaded in your fiddle.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Damn, that was it. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('td > img.theimage', this)` to target the images in the row that you're currently hovering over. Instead of using `.css()`, you can simply set the height with `.height()`. However, there is no change back because you did not include that in your original code, it would be relatively easy to add though. You can see the changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/J2YAj/3/